# How to get a mysql output to a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here I have two variables called $semresult, $examresult where i need to store the results of two respective queries. And then I need to do a calculation with them. The code I tried so far is

```
  $output = '';  
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "crudnew");  

        $semfee = "select sum(amount) from semesterfees";
        $semresult = mysqli_query($connect,$semfee);

        $examfee = "select sum(amount) from examfees";
        $examresult = mysqli_query($connect,$examfee);

        $income = ((int)$semresult + (int)$examresult);
```

But whenever I run the above code $semresult, $examresult gets the error "object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int". Please help :')

Comment: You haven't understand what you should pass to the `query()` function. I recommend you to google for it, then you'll see you've to pass the connection + the query string, not the result name.

Comment: you should pass the actual queries (semfee and examfee) and then use the mysqli_fetch functions to fetch the actual result and use it in the calculations

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, i corrected it in the above code, now there's a new error "object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int" to those $semresult, $examresult variables

Comment: Can you give us the output of $semresult and $examresult?

Comment: try `mysqli_fetch_array` after `mysqli_query` for accessing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$semfee = "select sum(amount) as total from semesterfees";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$semfee);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$semresult = $row['total'];
```

And then you do the same for the second query.

Here you can read more about [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) and what it does.

Comment: Consider elaborating regarding the fetcg_assoc function for a better solution practice.

Comment: Thanks friend!! Your solution worked for me....I have much to learn :')

Answer (score 0):

You are passing invalid query. Please check once try this

```
    $semfee = "select sum(amount) from semesterfees";
    $semresult = mysqli_query($connect,$semfee );

    $examfee = "select sum(amount) from examfees";
    $examresult = mysqli_query($connect,$examfee);

    $income = ((int)$semresult['amount'] + (int)$examresult['amount']);
```